# How does driver and application version compatibility work in Linux?

Tags: drivers, raid

If a hardware driver or application publisher states that their softwate works on Ubuntu 16.04, will it also work on 20.04? Does it mean that you have to have **AT LEAST** 16.04 to use it? Or is it just hit and miss?

I'm running into this a lot when looking for RAID controllers, and they say that it works with 16.04 but the version never goes higher. I'm looking for a decent performance RAID controller that'l handle 16 bays and also provide a GUI management utility.

Sorry for the newb question.